# How do collect all dependencies for multi modules

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

Collect all the dependencies for multi modules

I have modules shown as below:

```
parent
  |_module1
  |_module2
  |_distribution
```

parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    </modules>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>distribution</id>
            <modules>
                <module>distribution</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Distribution pom.xml

```
<project>
    <artifactId>distribution</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I would like to collect all dependencies base on the profile.

profile1: all dependencies includes module1 and module2 jar itself.

profile2: all dependencies excludes module1 and module2 jar itself.
Profile2 mainly for development environment. We just need the dependency jars in the server, and we use Eclipse to deploy the module1 and module2 on the fly to the server.

I have tried to use maven-assembly to get all dependencies includes module1 and module2, but I don't how to have conditional in maven assembly to include / exclude module jar.

Thanks

Comment: First never make define a [module in a profile](https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/) apart from that the maven-assembly-plugin is the correct way to go for example see https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee

Comment: Thanks for replying @khmarbaise. The reason for defining the module inside a profile because this distribution module is only called by need. I have take a look on your code, but I couldn't find which configuration to exclude module jar in dependencies folder?

Comment: A module which is used should run always..cause this will cause issues after releases etc. You need to read the documentation about [assembly descriptors](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html)